# I want to dynamically add row data to HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have two input fields, `date` and `miles`.
The HTML table has those columns. How do I grab the input values and on "submit" button, insert that data into a new row in the table?

```
var mileSubmit = document.getElementById("add-mileage");

mileSubmit.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const date = document.getElementById("date_miles").value;
  const mileage = document.getElementById("miles").value;
  console.log(date, mileage);
  document
    .getElementById("mile_book")
    .appendChild(document.createElement("tr"));
});
```

```
<form class="miles_form">
    <label for="date">Date:</label>
    <input type="date" id="date_miles" name="date_miles">

    <label>Enter Current Mileage:</label>
    <input name="mileage" type="number" id="miles">

</form>

<table id="mile_book">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Mileage</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `td` elements and append them to the `tr` element that you created.

```js
var mileSubmit = document.getElementById("add-mileage");

mileSubmit.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const date = document.getElementById("date_miles").value;
  const mileage = document.getElementById("miles").value;
  const row = document.createElement("tr");
  const td1 = document.createElement("td");
  td1.innerText = date;
  row.appendChild(td1);
  const td2 = document.createElement("td");
  td2.innerText = mileage;
  row.appendChild(td2);
  document
    .getElementById("mile_book")
    .appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<form class="miles_form">
  <label for="date">Date:</label>
  <input type="date" id="date_miles" name="date_miles">
  <br>
  <label>Enter Current Mileage:</label>
  <input name="mileage" type="number" id="miles"><br>
  <button type="button" id="add-mileage">Add</button>
</form>

<table id="mile_book">
  <tr>
    <th>Date</th>
    <th>Mileage</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: my cells came up empty in the rows after this method

Comment: I don't have a crystal ball, I can't tell what you did differently.